Use linker on M1 macOS to link bash and C files to compile simple kernel
I am following this tutorial on M1 MacBook (macOS Sonoma 14.5):
https://github.com/debashisbarman/Simple-Kernel-in-C-and-Assembly.
The kernel should connect to C.
I have following three files with the code from the tutorial:

kernel.asm
linker.ld
kernel.c

These two commands work okay:
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o

gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o

The problem comes when I try to link the files using elf.
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o

I get the following error:
ld: file not found: elf_i386

the kernel should run in emulator after this step
qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel

I have read an answer that tells me I cannot do this on macOS:
MacOS assembly linker throws error while linking
I managed to install i686-elf-ld, but even this command fails with ld: file not found: i686-elf-ld error:
ld -m i686-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o

My question is: how exactly can I perform the linking and emulating commands on a Macbook with M1?
Is there any developer that managed to compile bare bones asm + C kernel on M1 Mac?
Thanks!

Maybe you meant to use i686-elf-ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o

Thanks, this seems to run, hover I get:
kc.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Did you compile with the cross compiler with: i686-elf-gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o ?

I now get i686-elf-ld: kasm.o: in function `start': kernel.asm:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `kmain'. In the tutorial there is kmain in assembly and k_main with underscore in the C file. It  even showed same error while I unified the names. The entire code is in the link in my question.

You have to use the same name in both. So make them all kmain or all k_main - not a combination of both.

Thank you so much! It finally works!  You are the best! @MichaelPetch

No problem, good luck!
